# Rabbit MQ how to proxy web console from Apache

Tags: apache, proxy, rabbitmq, reverse-proxy

I have just started with RabbitMQ, the web console opens at **http://<>:15627/** but as this port is blocked, then i need to Proxy it. But I already have below config for another service.

ProxyPass / http://localhost:6060/
I have below questions now:-

 1. Is it secure to open web console in production as anybody can do a hit n trial for username/pass.

 2. If yes then how can i Proxy another one for Rabbit Web console. Can I add a path on which Web console will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using ssh Port forwarding which is a secure way as Data transmitted over ssh will be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using Apache reverse proxy. Here is an example vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName messagebroker.mydomain.com
  Redirect 301 / https://messagebroker.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName messagebroker.mydomain.com

  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:15672/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:15672/

  ProxyErrorOverride On

  Include /etc/apache2/ssl/godaddy-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
```